# Rails, Gritter - remove default title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gritter

I use [Gritter](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter) notifications in Rails 5 app and can't find a way to remove default title of the notification popup. I add Gritter as bellow:

```
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice], title: 'I dont need you', sticky: false) %>
```

Tried:

```
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice], title: false, sticky: false) %>
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice], title: nil, sticky: false) %>
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice], title: '', sticky: false) %>
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice], title: ' ', sticky: false) %>
```

And still popup appears with the default title - "Notification". Tried to search in the whole app's project "Notification" or "gritter", but nothing related was found.

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_gritter` method in the gem sets the `options[:title]` as "Notification" if `options[:title].blank?` returns true.

The "dirty" option is to define it again, with a hash of options instead `*args`, and to render the title if it was passed as an option argument, like:

```
def add_gritter(text, options={})
  if %w(success warning error notice progress).include?(options[:image].to_s)
    options[:image] = image_path("#{options[:image]}#{options[:image].to_s == 'progress' ? '.gif' : '.png'}") 
  end
  notification = Array.new
  notification.push("jQuery(function(){") if options[:nodom_wrap].blank?
  notification.push("jQuery.gritter.add({")
  notification.push("image:'#{options[:image]}',") if options[:image].present?
  notification.push("sticky:#{options[:sticky]},") if options[:sticky].present?
  notification.push("time:#{options[:time]},") if options[:time].present?
  notification.push("class_name:'#{options[:class_name]}',") if options[:class_name].present?
  notification.push("before_open:function(e){#{options[:before_open]}},") if options[:before_open].present?
  notification.push("after_open:function(e){#{options[:after_open]}},") if options[:after_open].present?
  notification.push("before_close:function(e){#{options[:before_close]}},") if options[:before_close].present?
  notification.push("after_close:function(e){#{options[:after_close]}},") if options[:after_close].present?
  notification.push("on_click:function(e){#{options[:on_click]}},") if options[:on_click].present?
  notification.push("title:'#{escape_javascript(options[:title])}',") if options[:title].blank? # Here
  notification.push("text:'#{escape_javascript(text)}'")
  notification.push("});")
  notification.push("});") if options[:nodom_wrap].blank?
  text.present? ? notification.join.html_safe : nil
end
```

But the gritter.js file has an `if` to check if the `title` has any content, so you should have to deal with your own and edit it, just to check for the text, like:

```
//We might have some issues if we don't have a title or text!
if (!params.text) {
  throw 'You need to fill out the text parameter.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like a best way, but works. If any other solutions - please feel free :)

```
.gritter-title {
  display: none;
}
```

Edit:

Since I use SCSS, this is better:

```
<%= js add_gritter(flash[:notice], sticky: false, :on_click => remove_gritter, :time => 100000, class_name: 'no-title') %>
.no-title {
  .gritter-title {    
      display: none;
  }
}
```